# For loop and execution order

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop followed by a line of code (a done statement from mocha).

Will there be a situation where done() would be executed before the loop is complete? How does execution order work in javascript for a scenario like this?

```
for (let i=0; result.length < i; i++) {
  assert.equal(result[i].priority, 6);
}
done();
```

Comment: `done()` would always run after the loop is complete. *However*, the body of the loop may invoke some (possibly asynchronous) work that may or may not be completed by the time `done()` is executed.

Comment: why are you asking this? what's your problem?

Comment: @haim770 so if I'm writing non-async code in the loop it would still execute done() after, no matter the total size of the operations inside the loop?

Comment: @darkace, True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done will never be called before the loop is "done". But the definition of "done" looks strange in your loop.

The for loop should be

```
for(let i=0; i < result.length; i++){
    assert.equal(result[i].priority, 6);
}
```

When you only use result.length, it will skip the loop completely if result contains anything, since a positive number is a truthy value.

Comment: Good spot. Actually it should have been `i < result.length`

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't dynamically loading scripts or marking them as defer or async, then scripts are loaded in the order encountered in the code. It doesn't matter whether it's an external script or an inline script - they are executed in the order they are encountered in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small fiddle as a POC https://jsfiddle.net/66ppporc/
`done()` would always be called after the loop is complete.

And a quick read for you http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to execute a function before the loop ends you can doo something like this

```
for (let i=0; result.length; i++) {
  assert.equal(result[i].priority, 6);
    if(condition) {
           break; // stops the loop
           done(); // execute function here
        }
    continue; // continue the loop until it ends
}
```